# Clojure gen-class for overloaded and overridden methods

Tags: java, clojure, interop, gen-class

I'm trying to use `gen-class` to override the `compare(WriteableComparable a, WriteableComparable b)` method in [this class](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.html#compare(org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable,%20org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable)) in clojure. The complication comes from the fact that this method is overloaded 3 times:

- `int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b)`
- `int compare(Object a, Object b)`
- `int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2)`

So far my attempt looks like this:

```
(gen-class
 :name comparators.MyWriteableComparator
 :extends org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator
 :exposes-methods {compare superCompare}
 :prefix "interop-")

(defn interop-compare
  ([this a b c d e f]
     (.superCompare this a b c d e f))
  ([this ^WritableComparable w1 ^WritableComparable w2]         
     (.compareTo (.getSymbol ^SymbolPair w1) 
                 (.getSymbol ^SymbolPair w2))))
```

Everything compiles, but when I run it, I'm getting a null pointer exception, and I suspect that it is because I overrode the wrong method (i.e. the `compare(Object a, Object b)` instead of the intended `compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b)`). [For reference](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.19.1-hudson-3/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparator.java/?v=source), the `Object` version of `compare` calls through to the `WriteableComparable` version.

It's totally possible that the NPE is coming from something else, but I've at least narrowed it down to this clojure code (when I run it with the corresponding Java version, things work well).

Is there a way to specify which overloaded version of the method should be used?

(I tried adding a `:methods` clause into the `gen-class` call, but I learned that one should declare only new methods, not superclass methods.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a mechanism that works with `gen-class` and allows overriding same arity overloaded methods. We can define vars / functions with names that include the types of the arguments in addition to the prefix and the method name. To override a method like `foo(String s, Object o)` we can define a var named `-foo-String-Object`. The code will look for a var thus named before falling back to `-foo`. This is documented at least in [one of the Clojure mailing list threads](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/TVRsy4Gnf70).

In practice, this means that you can write code like:

```
(defn interop-compare [this a b c d e f]
  (do-array-compare))

(defn interop-compare-Object-Object [this a b]
  (do-object-compare))

(defn interop-compare-WritableComparable-WritableComparable [this a b]
  (do-writable-comparable-thing))
```

Comment: Wow.  One more way in which use of `gen-class` is a dark art.  I had wondered about this question, but didn't need an answer, so put it out of my mind.

Comment: For my future reference, you need to add to :methods duplicate entry for interop-compare, one of input Object Object and one of input WritableComparable-WritableComparable for this to work.